# How to synchronize MySQL database with Amazon OpenSearch service

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am new to Amazon OpenSearch service, and i wish to know if there's anyway i can sync MySQL db with Opensearch on real time. I thought of Logstash but it seems like it doesn't support delete , update operations which might not update my OpenSearch cluster

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to comment for **Elasticsearch** as that is the tag used for this question.

You can:

- Read from the database (`SELECT * from TABLE`)
- Convert each record to a JSON Document
- Send the json document to elasticsearch, preferably using the `_bulk` API.

Logstash can help for that. But I'd recommend modifying the application layer if possible and send data to elasticsearch in the same "transaction" as you are sending your data to the database.

I shared most of my thoughts there: http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/05/09/advanced-search-for-your-legacy-application/

Have also a look at this ["live coding" recording](https://www.elastic.co/fr/blog/how-to-add-powerful-search-existing-sql-applications-elasticsearch-video-tutorial).

---

**Side note**: If you want to run Elasticsearch, have look at [Cloud by Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/cloud), also available if needed from  [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Elasticsearch-Inc-Elasticsearch-Service-on-Elastic/B01N6YCISK), [Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/elastic.ec-azure?tab=Overview) and [Google Cloud Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/endpoints/elasticsearch-service.gcpmarketplace.elastic.co).

Cloud by elastic is one way to have access to **all features**, all managed by us. Think about what is there yet like Security, Monitoring, Reporting, SQL, Canvas, Maps UI, Alerting and built-in solutions named [Observability](https://www.elastic.co/observability), [Security](https://www.elastic.co/security), [Enterprise Search](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search) and what is coming next :) ...

**Disclaimer**: I'm currently working at Elastic.

Comment: How do u keep both systems consistent in case database succeeded and elasticsearch failed without rolling back the transaction?

Comment: You can rollback the database but IMO it's better not to rollback and log that info. That way you don't loose what the user has entered. You need then to send the data again to ES. Or you could write the failing document to a message queue system and as soon as ES is back, read the queue and index the documents again.

Comment: From your experience, Do u think sending data to database and a message to a queue system is better (which will eventually send the same data to elasticsearch) OR maybe send the data to the database then to elasticsearch directly and only if elasticsearch fails I'd then send it to message queue system instead?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a column that indicates when the row was last modified, then you will be able to do updates to OpenSearch. Similarly for deleting, just have a column indicating whether it is deleted or not (soft delete), and the date it was deleted.

With this db design, you can send the "delete" or "update" actions to OpenSearch/ElasticSearch to update/delete the indexes based on the last modified / deleted date. You can later have a scheduled maintenance job to delete these rows permanently from the database table.

Lastly, this article might be of help to you [How to keep Elasticsearch synchronized with a relational database using Logstash and JDBC](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash)